# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details in magento2.3.3

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, static-content-deploy

I had run ***"setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB"*** command, my website shows

> "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details."

i checked in my log file,

```
CRITICAL: No host configured to connect {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 0): No host configured to connect at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:389)"} []
```

I can't run any command in my SSH.

Please help me

Comment: Can you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade?

Comment: Yeah, but i had an error like "In Abstract.php line 144:
                                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory " My mysql is not running in bitnami

Comment: You should check your database, I think your database doesn't work.